# Верстка элемента (угол)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сверстать такой элемент, в частности нижнюю полосу?

Comment: Посмотрите по ссылке, там ответ есть, только в обратную сторону, по аналогии  думаю уже догадаетесь как

Answer (score 3):

как то так)

```css
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 218px;
}
.hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.hover span {
    background: #FBD232;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
}
.hover span:before {
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid #FBD232;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: -12px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxeKS.png" />
<div class="hover">Простые <span>от 800 Р</span></div>
</div>
```